# Pg admin not have en US collation, but postgres hawe it

Tags: postgresql

**postgre 192.168.0.55**

```
 12342 | en_US.utf8             |            11 |  en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8 |
 12343 | ru_RU.utf8             |            11 |  ru_RU.utf8  | ru_RU.utf8 |
 12344 | en_US                  |            11 |  en_US.utf8  | en_US.utf8 |
 12345 | ru_RU                  |            11 |  ru_RU.utf8  | ru_RU.utf8 |
```

**pgadmin 192.168.0.77**

pgadmin 192.168.0.77 not have en US collation:
[image: pgadmin 192.168.0.77 not have en US collation IMAGE]